# What does bazel alwayslink = true mean?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm new to bazel. Here's the explanation in bazel doc:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.alwayslink

> alwayslink
>
> Boolean; optional; nonconfigurable; default is 0
>
> If 1, any binary that depends (directly or indirectly) on this C++
>   library will link in all the object files for the files listed in
>   srcs, even if some contain no symbols referenced by the binary. This
>   is useful if your code isn't explicitly called by code in the binary,
>   e.g., if your code registers to receive some callback provided by some
>   service.

I don't quite understand the last sentence: `e.g., if your code registers to receive some callback provided by some service.` Can anyone give and example? Thanks!

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? What a callback is, what services are in this context, or why this option helps with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> e.g., if your code registers to receive some callback provided by some service.

AIUI, this is the case when the `cc_binary` builds a shared library / a DLL. You need the linker to keep all symbols, even if unused, because another binary who loads the .so/.dll at runtime might need those symbols.

Comment: Is this true for the apple_binary rule as well?

Comment: What are you referring to by "this"?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. "This" means "keep all symbols, even if unused, because another binary who loads the .so/.dll at runtime might need those symbols".

And after some testing I think I can assume setting alwayslink to true works the same way for apple_binary as it does for cc_binary

Comment: Oh OK, thanks for clarifying! Yes, sounds like it should work. And if it does, great! :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation! It solved a bug of mine. I want to build a binary `A`, deps include library `B`, and library `B`'s dep include lib `C`. Without add `alwayslink` in B's cc_libary, I can compile binary A but it runs with error. even I add `C` directly into `A`'s deps list it won't work. Binary `A` works after I add `alwayslink` in libary `B` .

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Most linkers will remove object files if they are unreferenced by the rest of the program, even if they contain dynamic initialization.

For example:

```
struct S { S(); }

S s;

S::S() {
   std::cout << "Hello, World!";
}
```

This code prints `Hello, World!` during dynamic initialization.  The constructor of the global variable `s` prints it, and that is called during dynamic initialization.

If you link this code with a program, it might be removed, so `Hello, World!` will not be printed by the program.

The `alwayslink` flag prevents this, and forces the program to include the dynamic initialization.

The usual use case for this is when the dynamic initialization causes registration of stuff.  For example it might be a "plugin" for some application, and its dynamic initialization adds it to the global list of plugins.

It has nothing to do with shared vs static libraries.

Comment: Also, see the example given in this bug report: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3949